# Blender crashing when put in background

Tags: error

When I put Blender in the background for some minutes, it likes to stop responding. But this time, the console was open and I got this message:

```
AL lib: (EE) ALCmmdevPlayback_mixerProc: WaitForSingleObjectEx error: 0x102
```

Can you tell me what that means? Googling it only brings up Minecraft Stuff

My Specs:

- Win 10 x64
- Blender v2.78 using Blender Render
- AMD Radeon™ RX 460
- 8 GB RAM

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of Blender do you have? Which render engine are you using at the time? Do you have Blender running anything in the background?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of audio issue, AL lib is related to sound I think. Either there is a bug in Blender, or an issue with your computer.

Comment: @ScottMilner Sometimes I let it render in the background, but this time it was actually doing NOTHING

Comment: it happened again. I tabbed out for like 5 seconds and booom - no response. Console shows absolutely nothing. Weirdly the music from the sequence editor was still running...